# Segurança Autenticação Token Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, autenticação, token, django-rest-framework

Bom pessoal eu estou usando o DRF(sou novato rs), para montar uma pequena API. O problema vem na autenticação... pensando em expandir futuramente minha API para usar em um app mobile, eu já venho querendo utilizar o token authentication. Ta tudo funcionando as mil maravilhas porém eu não sei onde salvar o token em uma aplicação web. Salvar o token em um cookie não me parece nada seguro :/ Queria saber qual a melhor forma de salvar o token em uma aplicação web. Seria melhor criar uma api para mobile(token) e outra para web(sessão e cookie) ? Agradeço desde já :D

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro usar [SessionAuthetication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) para versão web e [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) para versão mobile, já que é possível usar mais de um esquema de autenticação devido à forma como a autenticação é [determinada](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined). O próprio DRF usa SessionAuthentication em sua BrowsableApi, [aqui](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-login-to-the-browsable-api) ele adiciona as `rest_framework.urls` que apontam para as views de login e logout do Django.

Comment: Esse Hugão é fera mesmo!!!!